# getFragmentManager( ) and support package

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-support-library, android-screen-support

I'm learning to use fragments for build a dynamic application, but I've a problem with the Fragment Manager. When I pass it by the method getFragmentManager( ) is shown a warning because it returns the Fragment Manager of android.app, not from the support library.
Do you know how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`

Also, make sure you are extending `FragmentActivity` and not just `Activity`.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem! Thanks a lot! I should read slower XD